# ACTION OPEN DOCUMENT TREE only returns empty Recent folder

Tags: android, file-io

I have carefully copied the following code snippet from an earlier posting and it works, on the simulator and also on my Nexus 9 device, up to a point !

However, all I get is an empty Recent folder and I never reach the code that writes a file.

What must I change to get a proper document tree ?

```
   private void testDocumentTree() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
            String TAG = "onActivityResult";
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
                DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);

                // List all existing files inside picked directory
                for (DocumentFile file : pickedDir.listFiles()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Found file " + file.getName() + " with size " + file.length());
                }

                // Create a new file and write into it
                DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("text/plain", "My Novel");
                try {
                    OutputStream out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());
                    out.write("A long time ago...".getBytes());
                    out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File Not Found, reason: ", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"IOException, reason: ", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: FWIW, I added an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202116

Answer (score 14):

Others mentioned the option on DocumentsUI which the user should manually enable. However there is another option. Add these extras on to your ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, ACTION_GET_CONTENT ,ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent. Explore button on Storage settings uses these extras while opening DocumentsUI app. I think the first one is enough to show Internal storage and sdcard. The others are good to have.

```
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);
```

---

#### Android 10

I tried on Android 10 emulator and OnePlus 7T, "SHOW_ADVANCED" extra does not do anything. User should manually click to "Show Internal storage" on the three dot menu. SDCards are visible by default.

Comment: lol what do they do? What do these magical strings do? They work but they don't show up when you search google/bing for them.

Comment: I found they by reading AOSP source code. I noticed that Explore button on Storage settings on stock Android opens DocumentsUI app with visible internal storage. It is like private API, thus all devices may not behave same way.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this actually makes a difference (on Android 10)? I've tried it for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE on Android 10 and cannot see any benefit.

Comment: @fthdgn thanks for checking. How about those other two extras?

Comment: For Android 10+ it's better to use `ContentResolver`,  `MediaStore` and its `MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames(context)` method

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you do.

I clicked "Show internal storage" in the overflow menu

[image]

After that I was able to see "Internal storage" in the drawer

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering why they only show files that were downloaded or are pictures by default....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking but in the folder picker, where you're seeing only the recent folder, there's a overflow menu where you can toggle between show/hide SD Card.

[image: Overflow menu]

Comment: Tried this. Still only shows Recent (on emulator) with no other options.

Comment: Did you set the sd card size when creating the emulated device?

Answer (score 0):

For me its working on emulator but not on real Android 5 phone.
I even checked google android Directory Selection sample and it also did not work.

So, its surely a bug whose effect can be seen on some phones.

Report this bug to google and wait till it is fixed. Till then all you can do is to restrict access to memory card in your app, which is what you may not want to do. But I think there is nothing that we can do from our side before google fixes it.

If you get any workaround for this you can tell me too.