# When using Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree can you allow the user to save in a location off the device?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, savefiledialog

This is a Xamarin project but I think the code mostly just wraps the android sdk. When I pick a file I use/get this:

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
intent.AddCategory (Intent.CategoryOpenable);
StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (intent, "Select file"), 0);
```

[image]

Notice how it is capable of opening from remote locations. But when try to pick a directory I use/get this:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889377/action-open-document-tree-only-returns-empty-recent-folder
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);
StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (intent, "Select Save Location"), 0);
```

[image]

Am I missing something or is there no way to do this? For example, when choosing the save location I would like for the user to be able to choose Prime Photos if they have that.

Answer (score 4):

These intents use different APIs

- [ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) is the older one (since API level 1).
- [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) is part of the Storage Access Framework introduced in API level 19. Unfortunately this intent is not supported by any SAF provider I know of, not event Google Drive. As far as I know it is only used to access local storage (`android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED` is an undocumented extra showing the internal storage root)

While not as widely implemented as one would like, the SAF is still usable. You can use :

- [ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT) if you want to save a single document (as opposed to let the user choose a subtree where you can write multiple documents or create subdirectories)
- [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) to select an existing document.

See [Open files using storage access framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) for more details.

Comment: ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT was what I ended up using. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the mimetype of the document.

```
> public void performFileSearch() {
> 
>     // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
>     // browser.
>     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
> 
>     // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
>     // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
>     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
> 
>     // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
>     // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
>     // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
>     // it would be "*/*".
>     intent.setType("image/*");
> 
>     startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE); }
```

Comment: Okay I can do all of that except I don't have an existing URI since at this point the file only exists in memory. I'm trying to save a new file.

Comment: What is the extention of the file? From that you can get the mimetype https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

Comment: You don't necessarily need the URI object

Comment: I added `intent.SetDataAndType(null, "image/png");` but now instead of launching the directory picker it says "No apps can perform this action."

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way, you can't use `setDataAndType` when you have no data. Look at my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin to select a directory in android devices you can simply use PortableStorage which is one of my project. It uses ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE via SAF and does exactly what you need.
https://github.com/madnik7/PortableStorage

Comment: Good stuff! This is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Does this come with File or directory both selectable option?

Comment: @iJay I haven't implemented it for selecting a single file, because in that case the return is just a stream not a storage (directory). I will think about it to add it as a utility method.