# How to Open and Read text files on Android in C#

Tags: c#, android

The code I have now is:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetType("text/plain");
        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select file"), 1);
        string str = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(?????);
```

That last line of course doesn't work. I'd like the user to be able to browse folders on the device and open one of them. This is simple in Windows but Android is proving difficult.

1/3/2023:
This issue is still unsolved. Coming from Windows and C# this is all trivial. But Android, not.

I have tried these:

var documents = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var documents = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory);
var documents = System.Environment.CurrentDirectorygetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);

With this I can see the file list in Documents. I can select one at a time but mostly I cannot open them. On rare occasion the OS asked me what app I should open the file with and that works, but only rarely.

When I open and save files in FXTextEdit (on Android) Why not in my app progammatically?

I am coding in C#.

9/6/2023:

When I use this code:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            intent.SetType("text/plain");
            intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
            intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
            intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select file"), 0);
```

I can access the Documents folder and select a file but then what? How do I open it (assuming it's an openable text file)? How do I read the data in the file? Or find out how large it is?

Thanks.

Comment: What about a different subject for your post?

Comment: "I'd like the user to be able to browse folders on the device and open one of them" -- there is no `Intent` action for that. Android works around an abstraction for storage; there is no practical means to somehow limit that to filesystem contents. Also, you will not have permissions to work with most of the filesystem. If you are willing to work with Android's storage abstraction, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50980397/115145 for some Xamarin-specific advice.

Comment: But whenever I look at code, it always involves intent. I'll check out your link. Thanks.

Comment: When using, say, FX (the program) it starts u with  a view of folders and some other link. I want something like that.. If the app cannot open a folder, no big deal. I'm looking to open text files only. With FX I'm presented with Documents and Download (among others). This would be OK.